# Getting the data from an AWS S3 bucket using a pre-singed URL (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-scraping

I am wondering how you would get the data from a pre-signed url from a S3 bucket, I have to use a pre-signed url because my bucket is private and thats the only I know how to access the data in an object in the bucket.

First I generate the pre-signed url using the bucket info with this code

```
var presignedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: 'BUCKETNAME',
    Key: 'KEY',
    Expires: 43200
})
```

But now i want to know how i would use that URL to get the data in that object in that particular bucket, I have tried the following code but it hasn't worked. Any suggestions?  Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", presignedUrl, true);
request.onload = () => {console.log(request.responseText)}
request.send();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hasn't worked"?  What specific errors or failures do you see?

Comment: I am sorry for not being specific, the error i'm getting is: GET "S3 PRE-SIGNED BUCKET LINK" (Not Found)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>key</Key><RequestId>RequestId</RequestId><HostId>HostId</HostId></Error>

Comment: NoSuchKey suggests that the bucket or the key that you indicated are incorrect.